# flutter: suffixIcon icon does not appear

Tags: flutter

In my `textField` I set a condition that when the length of a gets to 10, a `suffixIcon` should appear. However, it doesn't appear until I save the code again. Any help?

My code:

```
TextField(
                  inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)],
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  // onChanged: (value) {
                  //   phone.text = value;
                  // },
                  controller: phone,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Phone Number...",
                      hintStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600, fontSize: 20),
                      suffixIcon: phone.text.length == 10
                          ? const Icon(
                              Icons.done_outline,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              size: 40,
                            )
                          : null),
                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TextField(inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)],
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  // onChanged: (value) {
                  //   phone.text = value;
                  // },
                  controller: phone,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 40,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Phone Number...",
                      hintStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade600, fontSize: 20),
                      suffix: phone.text.length == 10
                          ? const Icon(
                              Icons.done_outline,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              size: 40,
                            )
                          : null),
                ),
```

use suffix don't use suffixIcon for it

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:-**
Its because of the state is not updating when text length is 10

**Solution:-**

```
 onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.length == 10) {
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
```

Comment: this partially worked. After I get the text.length == 10, the suffixIcon appears. However, when I delete a anything the icon doesn't disappear

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for both visible and disappear

```
 onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.length == 10 || value.length == 9) {
          setState(() {});
        }
      },
```